# Why does Stack Overflow discourage adding "[Solved]" to question titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

After posting a question, I found the answer myself, perhaps with a bit of help from the comments. To indicate to the community that it had been resolved, I appended "[Solved]" to my question's title. I also edited the question to include the answer.

Later, someone came along and reversed my edits to the question. Why did they make these changes? Now readers cannot see that my problem has been resolved!

What should I have done differently? I couldn't post an answer because my question had been closed in the mean time.

Answer (score 34):

The correct way to denote that a problem was resolved is to accept an answer. Even if you yourself provide that answer. There's no harm in that.

Comment: Why is that the correct way? What disadvantages ensue from using the title instead? (I don't disagree but I think the OP was hoping for a more extensive explanation)

Comment: That is the correct way because of the Q&A format that we use here.  Someone visiting the page is likely there to find an answer to the same problem.  A question always shows how many answers have been provided and the green box around the answer means that an answer was accepted (a.k.a The question was solved.)

Comment: ... and having an explicit answer helps others who are struggling with the same question.

Comment: While I completely agree (I landed here searching for a reference when asking someone not to add `SOLVED` to the title), it occurs to me that users might be encouraged to do this because way too many questions are actually _answered in the comment section_. Yes, users should then write an answer themselves, but in the first place people should stop giving answers as comments, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 13):

> To indicate to the community that it had been resolved

Stack Overflow and, by extension, the wider Stack Exchange network are different from forums where pre- / postfixes along the lines of "solved" are common. Our goal is to build a "library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming" (at least that is the *end goal*).

In that regard, a question is never "[re]solved", as *just* solving the problem that the author of the question is facing is never the goal. There is always a chance that a better, more detailed / informed answer is going to be posted.

> Now readers cannot see that my problem has been resolved

On the contrary, the system provides built-in ways of indicating that the question has answers and whether one of them was accepted, and the indication is quite prominent. It is also tightly integrated with the search functionality: one can filter questions by [not] having accepted answers, use the `isaccepted` search operator, etc.

Take a look at how the information is currently conveyed by the UI (as of December, 2022):

[image: screenshot of a question item on the "all questions" page with the post information provided in the left column ("26811 votes", "27 answers" on a green background with a tick icon prepended to indicate that there is an accepted answer)]

> I couldn't post an answer because my question had been closed

If a question is closed, it means that the community decided it needs *improvement* to be a good fit for the library, and thus at the very least (if it is on-topic in the first place) requires an edit *before* it should be answered.

Yes, the closure often prevents users from posting a solution, but an important thing to remember is that it is supposed to be a *temporary* state (unless, again, the post is off-topic) — given our goal to build a *long-lasting* repository of knowledge, there is no rush to post an answer.