# Why is it OK for someone to downvote my question without attempting to be helpful?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do I keep Android Studio from stopping my app when I close Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758996/how-do-i-keep-android-studio-from-stopping-my-app-when-i-close-android-studio)

Going into Stack Overflow, I thought this was a site designed to *help* people and answer their questions. Was I wrong to think that?

TL;DR:

1. Why is it okay for people to downvote a question just because they don't approve of it?
2. How is someone capable of having over 122,000 reputation if they are this unhelpful?
3. Is there somewhere that people new to Stack Overflow can go to get a rundown of how to use this site? Because as far as I can tell, the new user experience is absolutely dreadful.

This was my very first question on the site. I did a fair bit of research beforehand looking for an answer and found none (I am still a responsible asker). As soon as I ask this question, it gets downvoted. I don't know why, as far as I can tell, the question is clear, useful, and I actually did research before asking. But nonetheless I get a downvote, and I can only imagine that the reason is someone felt my question was just stupid.

I then got a comment on my question (I assume from the same guy who downvoted it) answering my question. Well, I guess he technically did, but he didn't actually answer it. Instead, he just said "Don't run it from Android Studio." A very unhelpful answer that didn't even answer my question.
I then replied to him for some clarification of both my question and his answer. No response.

About a week later, I figured it out myself and decided to help out other people by posting the answer to my question. But then I make the "unacceptable" mistake of adding "Solved: " to my question title. And the same guy comes back just to edit that out and comment "It is not acceptable here to add *solved* to your post."
So... this guy, with 122,000 reputation, not only didn't answer my question at all, but he just comes to it to belittle it?

Maybe I don't understand the reputation system, but isn't it supposed to mean that the *helpful* people get more reputation? How does this guy have so much when all he does is belittle and mock my question?

Comment: It is good idea for you to re-read this question now as an explanation why many people no longer comment on posts....

Comment: Hey you can't know who downvoted , that's how the system is built. It could be anyone, not necessarily the person who commented. There are thousands of people who open posts , leave a downvote and disappear. It's called digital democracy.

Comment: I really wish I understood why people take feedback and downvotes so damn personally. Perhaps it was just the usual clash of expectations about the site?

Comment: “Why is it okay for people to downvote a question just because they don't approve of it?” - If they find the question unhelpful, certainly, they can downvote it

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger People come to the site with the mission to ask a question / outsource effort. That is kind of detrimental when you essentially shouldn't be asking any questions for at least a couple of days while you learn the lay of the land.

Comment: @Gimby A clash of expectations it is.

Comment: Of note: [Why does Stack Overflow discourage adding "\[Solved\]" to question titles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829) [the only thing I'd like to mention, though, is that acceptance doesn't necessarily mean "solved" either - it can just as well mean that the answer is the most helpful for the OP]

Comment: It seems to be a fine question, though it looks like a duplicate. But its terseness and lack of context/information (even lacking version information) makes it difficult to distinguish from low effort work orders (many Stack Overflow users don't actual read what is written, but *skim for keywords* instead, possibly because they expect close to incomprehensible broken English, especially in the Android tag. Or simply because they are in a hurry). We are not mind-readers (of, for instance, the supposedly extensive research prior to asking the question).

Comment: It is probably [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593). And *"It is not enough to do the research. You must also show us that you have done the research."*

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger It is absolutely a clash of expectations. I have come to the conclusion that, as not-a-discussion-forum as Stack Overflow tries to be, it is effectively impossible for a website to enable user creation of content without people assuming it's supposed to be a discussion forum. Even Wikipedia wrestles with this. (Deleted my other comments, as I'm evidently too late to the game and OP developed a solid understanding.)

Comment: Downvoting is being helpful. Please research how to use a site before you use it. Like both [main] & this site. You also jump to (wrong) conclusions in the meantime.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'll tell you this. When my nephew grows up and becomes a programmer (big chance since he takes after me), there is no chance he is going to be able to use Stack Overflow effectively and there won't be anything I can do about that. The kid gets everything handed on a silver platter. He is going to need the sequel to Stack Overflow called Stack Overflow 4you. It had better involve short videos.

Comment: `I did a fair bit of research beforehand looking for an answer and found none (I am still a responsible asker)` From the question itself, I wouldn't have known. What had you tried before posting? How long or when did the abnormal functionality appear? Was it a few hours or one month? I would have voted to close a question consisting of two sentences on *any* Stack Exchange site because it lacks detail and evidence of research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA plenty of the best questions are a single sentence. Curators have even edited existing popular questions down to that length, consciously. Simple problems beget simple descriptions. Most of the effort before asking should go into figuring out *exactly what the problem is*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel one sentence questions highly upvoted? Maybe, back in 2010, 2011 and 2012. But today, a single sentence without showing any code, or showing any effort in trying to resolve the problem beforehand. If you know exactly where the problem lies, I'd imagine googling the solution would be the next step. I may be wrong, so I  defer to your expertise.

Comment: Only because every good one-sentence question has been asked. Showing code would actively make many of those questions worse, because either the code is fine and thus there is no question, or there is a flaw that invites debugging that is irrelevant to the intended how-to question. However, new technologies come up from time to time, and we shouldn't rule out the possibility of them opening up new, excellent one-sentence questions.

Comment: People can downvote any question that they perceive as being poorly researched, poorly formulated, or otherwise not useful. For example, I encountered a well-formulated question on how to perform a task in Java 1.0; I downvoted because that seems like a ridiculous thing to do in the first place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Because votes are just people's opinion. This is OK for the same reason that it's OK for people to upvote a question just because they like it.

   Note: If the *vast majority* of your questions are *strongly disliked* by *a large number* of users, then that's a pretty strong signal that you aren't writing questions that are suitable for Stack Overflow. It's not a perfect heuristic, but it's pretty good, and the system *does* use that feedback as a quality-control mechanism. This is basically the reason why the vote system exists, and, more specifically, why users are encouraged to downvote as they see fit. A single downvote is nothing to worry about. At most, you should take it for what it is: a signal that someone thought you question could be improved. If, after reviewing it, you don't see anything that needs improvement, then you don't need to take any further action.
2. Because reputation is earned by posting content that is helpful *within the SO model*. Reputation isn't a generic measure of whether people are helpful. You can have tons of SO rep without ever having held a door open for anyone.
3. Yes, the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) are designed to fulfill that purpose. We also have a community-maintained [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) here on Meta.

Those high-level points aside, it seems like everything that Ken White did was helpful. At least, he didn't do anything that was mean-spirited or *unhelpful*. He tried to guide you on how to use the site (what he says about adding "SOLVED" to your post and editing an answer into the question is precisely correct), and he gave you his opinion about how he'd solve the problem. Maybe you didn't find that advice useful; that's fair. You can certainly "take it or leave it", as the saying goes. He just posted a comment; it wasn't even an answer. No one is obligated to respond to you. This site is staffed by volunteers.

Absolutely no one "mocked" your question. This is a ridiculous exaggeration, and it undermines your credibility.

Getting this upset about a single downvote also kinda strains credibility, to be honest. So someone on the Internet didn't like something you posted? Surely this isn't the *first* time you've had that experience…

The voting system we use here works because it's symmetrical: there are upvotes and downvotes. [Voting is a quality-control mechanism.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) It is meant as a simple, friction-free way for users to express their assessment (i.e., *opinion*) of a post's clarity, usefulness, suitability to the site, and interestingness. Everyone has their own criteria for how they vote. Voting is also [anonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts); you have no idea who voted which way on your posts, and [you shouldn't make assumptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) about it, because most of them are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for those links, they are very helpful. And you're right, I just misunderstood the purpose of this site.

It's not a site for asking questions YOU need help with, it's a site for asking questions OTHERS would find useful.

Comment: Actually, it's a site to "build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming" (quote from the [tour]). We're like Wikipedia, except that instead of long-form articles, the information is broken up into bite-size chunks using a question-and-answer format. So, there are [very specific rules about what types of questions are allowed](/help/on-topic). But…you didn't even make that mistake. Your question was fine by SO standards. The voting system doesn't, by itself, indicate a Q is inappropriate. It is only a ranking system. You didn't win question of the day.

Comment: @DavidGates lets not forget that research comes before asking questions, eh? The site already has more questions than it can possible handle, we need less of them and that means more people realising that asking questions is a last resort. The button is there, use it when you need it. But do be sure you actually need it.

Comment: `Getting this upset about a single downvote also kinda strains credibility, to be honest` it's now ten downvotes, no doubt caused by the meta effect. If the OP were a 19-year-old kid, would you still be unsympathetic? Having your very first post downvoted can be humiliating. But sometimes it's a good thing, not being humiliated, but realising we are not so "special" that we are immune to criticism. In fact, we learn to shoulder (constructive) criticism.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Yeah, definitely the Meta effect, and, while I'm all about downvoting, this isn't a case where I've downvoted the question, nor a case where I understand why so many others are downvoting the question. Regarding my lack of sympathy: yes. :-) I don't see why a 19-year-old (who isn't really a kid) would be any more "humiliated" than anyone else by finding out that someone, somewhere on the Internet disagreed with them and/or disliked something they posted. I was around that age when I started using Stack Overflow. "Humbling" is, perhaps, the word you're looking for.