# How can I understand this moderator activity on my questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, moderation

When I opened Stack Overflow just now, I saw that a moderator had edited some of my questions and answers.

[image]

This was probably triggered by some comments under the following post where I was active most recently:

[discory.py bot keeps RESUMING session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76678482/discory-py-bot-keeps-resuming-session#comment135187532_76678482)

Many of the comments were deleted because it was purely a discussion with another user, I understand, but what I don't understand is the following thing:

- Specifically here, the moderator removed a line that I kindly added because one comment under the question asked for the following in literal sense: "*Please don't post pictures, makes stuff untraceable*".

The comment is still visible and has not been removed – so seems relevant. My edit, however, has been removed. Is there a "*That's too much/unnecessary text*" rule here in that case, despite the picture? Everything else from my edit is still visible as it clearly improved the post.

Also with some other questions, which I have asked or answered months ago, strange edits have been made, which I on the first instance don't quite understand:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66941332/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76679903/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76678482/revisions

Here either single introductions were deleted or unnecessary rollbacks, in my opinion, were made. I can understand that you want to get to the point as quickly and clearly as possible, but where are such edits justifiable/necessary?

A post of mine was also just locked for **7 days**, with the following note:

> Content dispute

After removing a lot of the question, which I asked for, when one question results in two, my self-inserted "SOLVED" was also removed. While Stack Overflow [advises against it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles), I only didn't delete or otherwise edited the question because I gave myself the answer. Deleting the question would likely have impacted my account, so I refrained from doing so and also refrained from giving myself a less-than-qualitative answer of "*A new installation helped*".

Why is this question now locked for exactly 7 days?

All in all, I feel very uncomfortable when apparently a moderator arbitrarily goes through my questions and answers, makes minimal or major changes and I can't understand the reasons.

Comment: The first two edits in the list of 3 were very much correct, the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76679903/revisions) in particular, they are not what I'd call "strange". They remove bloated, chatty text, and are clearly good edits. The third is... more complicated, but it's _generally_ agreed that you shouldn't transcribe images on behalf of OP. "SOLVED" should _never_ be added to a question, just **post a self answer**, *"I only didn't delete or otherwise edited the question because I gave myself the answer"* is not an excuse.

Comment: It does look like you like to add "thank you notes" to posts - it is perfectly fine when those get removed (i.e. I did that to this post). If you think that duplicate ("remove fluff") posts does not exactly explain why such text is removed please [edit] this post to clarify. If your actual question "why moderator looked at my post" - it looks like you self-answered it with "probably triggered by some comments under the following post"...

Comment: Note that frequently questions get locked for 3-7 days if there is a lot of heated discussion or some sort of edit war going on.

Comment: @Nickistired "*They remove bloated, chatty text, and are clearly good edits*" – Why is StackOverflow so special about this? I understand that it's not a chatting platform, but these words don't really harm anyone and I still give a valid answer/question. "*"SOLVED" should never be added to a question*" – Do we have a specific rule about this somewhere? I did link a post in my question but for me, it did not sound like it's forbidden. My question her also aims to clarify why the moderator did edits to the specific posts, as there were weeks/months in between them. Did they perhaps get flagged?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Perfectly fine. I see that there's some sort of “dislike” among those phrases/words at the beginning or end of a post? I just feel like the term "fluff" is one that's very up to the one handling the current post/very subjective.

Comment: A question is expected to be a question, the whole question, and nothing but the question. Its the same for answers; they are at their best when they are 100% focused on answering the question. Convey the information; everything else is chaff. There probably is a posting on why one should not add SOLVED, but it will come down to, "That's what duplicate closure and the green checkmark are for." If there is no on-site duplicate and no formal answer, write an answer then give it the green checkmark.

Comment: @user4581301 So in my case, an answer like “I solved it by reinstalling `mysql`” is valuable/helpful for others who maybe come across this? I do get the point of the green checkmark, don't get me wrong. Leaving the question open that way was not an option for me, nor was it an option to delete it. I am not a fan of simple “Solved it by X” answers, especially to my own questions, as I want to keep a certain standard, but if that's the way to go I probably have to adapt!

Comment: A "I solved it by reinstalling sql answer" would be negligent if it did not outline the steps involved, even if the steps were 1) Download  most recent version. 2) Run installer. Usually they aren't that simple and there's many stops and something sneaky in there. An even more useful answer, one likely to be upvoted would explain what tin the installation was corrupted and give a realistic take on how it could have happened and possibly could be avoided in the future. For example, reinstalling the compiler because of a corrupted header might have been avoided by making the headers read-only.

Comment: @user4581301 In the post itself, I even included an “Update” section in one of my edits where I explained that I removed every possible `config` file and simply uninstalled and then reinstalled `mysql`. For me, this is not a quality answer that I would post to my own question. Diving in deeper, after things are resolved, are just a waste of time if you ask me and possible further comments/recommendations/answer are likely not to be tested with the current state.

Comment: If the question can never receive a suitable answer, delete it.

Comment: *Did they perhaps get flagged?* - I'm the mentioned user (*a discussion with another user*) who discussed with you about the superfluous (SOLVED) phrase in the title, but beyond that short discussion, which was resolved for me after you responded and removed the phrase, I had no further interaction with you or any of your content. I was also surprised as I couldn't find the comments anymore in my history. Aside from that, I think most of the moderator edits are ok.

Comment: @Dominik - Putting an update section in a contribution is inappropriate, it’s not required, all users can see revision history of a contribution. What has changed between different revisions is crystal clear. Likewise, solutions to a question, should be submitted in a detailed answer instead as an edit to a question. As for those edits, it appears you got into a rollback war, between community users and a moderator resolved it. All those edits were appropriate.

Comment: @SecurityHound I was the only one editing the post, strange. "*... all users can see revision history of a contribution*" – They *could/can*, yes, but I doubt that many users do this... In the end you are right, yes, I should have removed “Update” or whatever I called it and just insert my new information.

Comment: Just as it is natural to [misspell Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/) as StackOverflow, it is natural to add "Edit:" or "Change:". But that  doesn't make it right. See for example *"[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011))"*  - *"Changelogs. For example: "EDIT: added more info as requested in comments". You don't need to tell people what you changed. "*

Comment: cont' - *There's a real changelog (revision history) that's visible to everyone upon clicking the edit card/link under a post, which takes you to the post's /revisions sub-page. And people who are following the post will get notifications about edits to the post."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Question has already been answered to my satisfaction – thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This answers addresses moderator action's concerns - the explanation of edits covered in [Should I remove 'fluff' (like greetings, signatures, "thanks", etc.) when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin) policy on removing all sort of greetings/comments/other text unrelated to a question or answer.

Moderators are expected (among other things) to review *users'* behavior either in response to flags, automated detection or just due to stumbling on a post. It looks exactly that happened in your case - moderator likely got alerted, probably due to flags on a particular post. Then they noticed a particular pattern in the style of a post and decided to investigate. As result they looked at several posts of yours to check if style was one-off or a consistent behavior. It looks like those edit achieved the desired effect - you've noticed those and came to meta to understand the reason.

Also, moderators are expected to set "cool off" periods by locking post with questionable/hostile activity (like edit wars, heated comments or just gross misunderstanding of the site). It is quite possible moderator decided to lock the post you referring to, so participants have time to read more on the site's policies or ask questions on meta like you did here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, does look straight forward in the linked post and 'Help Center'. Must be my “personal” touch in this case that I need to adapt in future questions/answers to avoid such things. Not a big fan of it, but that's not the right place to discuss my point of views on such things! :)

Answer (score 18):

> Here either single introductions were deleted or unnecessary rollbacks, in my opinion, were made. I can understand that you want to get to the point as quickly and clearly as possible, but *where are such edits justifiable/necessary?*

At the risk of [repeating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160) the [standard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/) [explanations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950), as well as repeating myself from other Meta posts:

These edits are justified and made necessary *by the fact that we want to get to the point as quickly and clearly as possible*. We take this very seriously, because Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**, and the purpose of questions **is not** simply to get the person asking out of a jam, but to contribute to a searchable library.

Phrasing like "A more unusual question today, but maybe someone can help me." wastes readers' time, but more than that it makes them feel like they are being excluded from a conversation between the asker and the answerer. In fact, there is no such conversation at all - except to the minimum extent necessary to make the question clear, and then that conversation is supposed to be cleaned up.

Keep in mind that even a very niche question like yours about a very specific situation has been viewed more than 200 times: the onlookers finding your question outnumber you and the lone person who answered you literally by orders of magnitude. (And then, really important, valuable questions can attract **millions** of views.)

I examined [the first case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66941332/revisions) you listed, which you say you "didn't quite understand". The edit, in my view, didn't go far enough, but proper editing requires some subject expertise in Python and the API being used, along with close reading to understand what happened step by step. I attempted to fix it; please have a look at [how it now stands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941332/) and see how much more neatly it flows - and if I misunderstood something, made a typo etc. please feel free to fix it.

> Specifically here, the moderator removed a line that I kindly added because one comment under the question asked for the following in literal sense: "Please don't post pictures, makes stuff untraceable".

We are [not supposed to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) transcribe images, but overall I think your changes had a positive net effect. For future reference, this reasoning is faulty:

> Removing "RESOLVED" because OP did not accept an answer even though it was made clear in a comment that the problem was solved

Questions [**should not** have a "solved" tag **for any reason**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266). Not as an explanation within the question body, not as text in the title, and not as a tag. Again, this is **not a discussion forum**; while we provide an accept checkmark so that OP can indicate "this answer worked for me", even having that feature is controversial; and anyway everything else is redundant with that. Regardless of whether OP was helped, questions that haven't been closed may be answered *indefinitely later*, and it is *an explicit part of the site design* that questions get new answers years later (for example, because a change in the underlying technology makes a better answer possible). So, if you edit something like that out of a question, please don't restore it in the title, even if it's true.

Comment: Thanks, pretty good sum-up as well, along with some new things. I know that the reasoning could be seen as faulty, but I did not come up with something convincing, as it was indeed my mistake here. Will take something with me out of this answer indeed for future things!

Answer (score 7):

The first 2 edits are removing "fluff" - non essential text which isn't relevant to your question and therefore potentially distracting.

The 3rd edit is just a plain bad edit grammar-wise, surprisingly by a diamond mod. Probably English isn't their first language, but that's a poor excuse - they should be refrain from editing if they aren't reasonably fluent in the language.

"I am" -> "im"/"Im" is an incorrect edit adding incorrect grammar/slang. I now did a rollback of this incorrect edit. Incorrect capitalization of *I* is *very* basic English also... and a classic thing to *fix* while doing edits, not to introduce. Similarly "its" vs "it's" is something that non-native English speakers often struggle with and something to look out for.

Comment: Worth noting, the 3rd "edit", was not an edit, it was a rollback.

Comment: @Nickistired  ...by me, after reading this meta post. As mentioned in this answer.

Comment: No, _their_ edit was a rollback

Comment: @Nickistired Well it was a bad rollback then, since fixing grammar mistakes and removing fluff are valid reasons to edit... Anyway it looks ok now, so it's no biggie.

Comment: I see, so it's more about the “fluff” in those questions/answer rather than the general answer. While these edits/rollbacks seem to be fine, at least in 2/3 cases, I still don't get why this somehow feels “targeted” – at least for me. These edits/rollbacks happened probably after removing my comments under a post, but is this considered “standard” if a moderator goes ahead and probably checks your account/questions/answers to do more?

Comment: It was a rollback to remove things like "solved" from the  post, @Lundin . I don't blame the mod for rolling that all back. That they then didn't edit the question to re-improve its grammar is tangentially relevant, as edit 4 (that fixed the grammar) also did things it shouldn't have.

Comment: @Dominik "targeted" - it is expected (and actually desired) behavior for moderators to review user's behavior if they spotted something concerning in a post they happen to see (I've added separate answer to cover that).

Comment: Which question are you referring to? At any rate, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76678482/861716) the moderator rolled back to revision 1 because everything following it was either irrelevant or added/inferred by *someone else* w/o reason. I don't think rolling back to revision 5 was the right thing to do.

Comment: FWIW I rolled it back thinking the edit was invalid and only then realized the bad part was already rolled back. I should have made an edit of my own but I did not have the time.